# Swap gnews with ELMo in the simple colab tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow-hub, elmo

I'm working on this colab notebook:

https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_text_classification.ipynb

I'd like to replace the gnews swivel embeddings with the ELMo embeddings.

So, replace

```
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
```

with:

```
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2"
```

There is a cascade of things that change here, such as needing

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

But I'm not understanding the graph shape I need to do this replacement successfully.   Specifically, I'm seeing.

```
#model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/gnews-swivel-20dim/1"
model = "https://tfhub.dev/google/elmo/2"

elmo = hub.Module(model, trainable=True, name="{}_module".format("mymod"))

hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(elmo, 
#                           output_shape=[3,20], 
#                           input_shape=(1,),
                           dtype=tf.string, 
                           trainable=True)

hub_layer(train_examples[:3])
```

Produces

```
<tf.Tensor 'keras_layer_14/mymod_module_14_apply_default/truediv:0' shape=(3, 1024) dtype=float32>
```

This seems fine. But:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# First, I have to build, because I no longer have eager executon.
model.build(input_shape=(None,1024))

model.summary()
```

Then this gives:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-54-8786753617e4> in <module>()
      4 model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
      5 
----> 6 model.build(input_shape=(None,1024))
      7 
      8 model.summary()

18 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in internal_convert_to_tensor_or_indexed_slices(value, dtype, name, as_ref)
   1381       raise ValueError(
   1382           "Tensor conversion requested dtype %s for Tensor with dtype %s: %r" %
-> 1383           (dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).name, value.dtype.name, str(value)))
   1384     return value
   1385   else:

ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype string for Tensor with dtype float32: 'Tensor("Placeholder_12:0", shape=(None, 1024), dtype=float32)'
```

What else is changing about the graph dimensions and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Keras is assuming the input to be `float32`:

> conversion requested dtype `string` for Tensor with dtype `float32`

You can tell that this is the input because of the name "Placeholder_12:0". Placeholder tensors are used for feeding data into the model.

The model `hub_layer` expects a string input so all you need to do is add an `Input` layer that specifies that

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
#add an input layer
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=tuple(),dtype=tf.string))
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.build(input_shape=(None,1024))

model.summary()
```

Results in:

```
Model: "sequential_4"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer (KerasLayer)     (None, 1024)              93600852  
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 16)                16400     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 17        
=================================================================
Total params: 93,617,269
Trainable params: 16,417
Non-trainable params: 93,600,852
_________________________________________________________________
```

With your modifcations and the above modification I was able to train using the colab notebook.